# WinAPI equivalent for Linux/POSIX pthread_wait/pthread_post

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I have an application which takes care of some syncronization problems, it relies heavily on the POSIX functions, sem_wait, pthread_join and sem_post, I'd like to know what are the winapi equivalents for these?

Comment: Windows API threading is quite different than pthreads. It boils down to the same things but all functions work differently. Most of the time you will use `WaitForMultipleObjects()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sem_wait()` -> [`WaitForSingleObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) on a [Semaphore object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/semaphore-objects)

`pthread_join()` -> [`WaitForSingleObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) on a [Thread object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/multiple-threads)

`sem_post()`-> [`ReleaseSemaphore()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-releasesemaphore) on a [Semaphore object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/semaphore-objects)

See [Using Semaphore Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-semaphore-objects) in MSDN's documentation.

Comment: Except using `WaitForSingleObject()` isn't used much, because as soon as you wait for a specific resource like a semaphore, you should probably also be waiting for an event etc telling your thread to stop waiting and close down gracefully. So you'd normally use `WaitForMultipleObjects()` in most scenarios.